# Placement of multiple tkinter entries starting at a particular value

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Given below is a sample code derived from my main project, I'm able to place several entries using a for loop but I want it to start the y placement from **150**(currently it starts from 80). The formula I used to place my entries is given as `dist` below, i.e `((i*30)+50)`. The distance between each entry is alright, thus I don't wish to change that, I merely wish to change the starting value.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
entries = []
root.geometry("500x500")
ing = []

for i in range(10):
    dist = ((i*30) + 50)
    en = Entry(root)
    en.place(x = "50", y=f"{dist}")
    entries.append(en)

def ent():
    for entry in entries:
        ing.append(entry.get())
    print(ing)

button=Button(root,text="get",command=ent).place(x="200", y="400")

root.mainloop()
```

Given below is my output, I want my whole list of entries to be pushed down and started from a greater y value.
[image]

Comment: whats the expected output and output you got

Comment: you dont have to pass as formatted string, just pass in d variable and try?

Comment: if u want the y to increase, then increase the value of `dist` nd try

Comment: @Cool Cloud There is no error in the code, I just don't know how to push my entries down. If I change my formula it also increases or decreases the gap between 2 entries(I don't want that to happen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to tackle this problem is by editing your formula for distance, and saying

```
for i in range(10):
    dist = ((i*40) + 100)
    en = Entry(root)
    en.place(x=50, y=dist)
    entries.append(en)
```

Hope this helped. Happy Coding

Cheers